# Why won't visual studio let me resolve git conflicts

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

I have a project stored in bitbucket (git). Some time ago, visual studio stopped letting me merge.

It detects conflicts, pops up the normal screen, I can push the merge button, and get the merge resolver UI where I can select the various bits of code, but closing that window does nothing.

Also, selecting take remote or take local does nothing.

If I manually shell out to git, I can resolve the conflict at in the command line normally (git add), and as soon as I do so, Visual studio automatically updates to note that the conflict is resolved.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Sounds you're using a custom Git version control provider and not the built-in support for Git. Which version of Visual Studio? And which version of whatever Git provider are you using?

Comment: @jessehouwing 2013 Ultimate. As far as I know I am using the default git provider.  I did not intentionally install any other git providers into visual studio (although I do have git and git tools installed on the box, it isn't integrated in any way into visual studio)